# Parse iOS PFTwitterUtils linkUser: doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform, twitter-oauth

So I am using Parse to link a user with their twitter account. In the app delegate I have the following:

```
[PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey:CONSUMER_KEY consumerSecret:CONSUMER_SECRET];
```

Then the button which the user clicks to link the user to facebook calls the following:

```
-(IBAction)twitterConnectPressed{
    NSLog(@"twitter");
    [PFTwitterUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError* error){
        NSLog(@"haha");
        if(succeeded){
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done!" message:@"Connected with Twitter!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            self.fbButton.backgroundColor = [TGAPublic grey];

        }else{
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:error.userInfo[@"error"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
}
```

However even though `linkUser:block:` is called it doesn't do anything at all. It doesn't create a pop up to log in to twitter like `[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:]` does and therefore doesn't end up calling the block either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFTwitterUtils does not appear to handle all cases on iOS.  In particular, if you do not have an account setup (Settings->Twitter) it does not fire up a web view and attempt to used web oauth.  Conversely if you have multiple Twitter accounts configured (again in Settings) then it doesn't appear to fire up an action sheet to allow you to select which account you'd like to link.

There's a great tutorial on how to do these things which exposes an extension to PFFacebookUtils here: http://natashatherobot.com/ios-twitter-login-parse/

It does not do linking though, just login, but should be a good basis to add linking.

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar problem with link/unlink methods for both PFFacebookUtils and PFTwitterUtils (v. 1.7.4).

The only way I managed to make it work was to replace them by, unfortunately, messing with internal Parse implementation of authData:

```
#import "TwitterAuthProvider.h"
#import "PFTwitterUtils.h"
#import "PFUser.h"

static NSString * const kTwitterKey = @"XXX";
static NSString * const kTwitterSecret = @"XXX";

@implementation TwitterAuthProvider    

- (instancetype)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey:kTwitterKey consumerSecret:kTwitterSecret];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setAuthData:(id)twAuthData forUser:(PFUser *)user {    
    static NSString * const kParseAuthDataKey = @"authData";
    static NSString * const kParseLinkedServiceNamesKey = @"linkedServiceNames";    
    static NSString * const kParseAuthProviderName = @"twitter";

    NSMutableDictionary *authData = [[user valueForKey:kParseAuthDataKey] mutableCopy] ?: [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    authData[kParseAuthProviderName] = twAuthData ?: [NSNull null];
    [user setObject:authData forKey:kParseAuthDataKey];
    [user setValue:authData forKey:kParseAuthDataKey];

    NSMutableSet *linkedServices = [[user valueForKey:kParseLinkedServiceNamesKey] mutableCopy] ?: [NSMutableSet set];
    if (twAuthData) {
        [linkedServices addObject:kParseAuthProviderName];
    } else {
        [linkedServices removeObject:kParseAuthProviderName];
    }
    [user setValue:linkedServices forKey:kParseLinkedServiceNamesKey];
}

- (void)linkWithCompletion:(PFBooleanResultBlock)completion {
    NSParameterAssert(completion != nil);

    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    PF_Twitter *twitter = [PFTwitterUtils twitter];
    [twitter authorizeWithSuccess:^(void) {
        [weakSelf setAuthData:[self twitterAuthData] forUser:user];
        [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!succeeded) {
                //revert
                [weakSelf setAuthData:nil forUser:user];
            }
            completion(succeeded, error);
        }];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        completion(NO, error);
    } cancel:^(void) {
        completion(NO, nil);
    }];
}

- (void)unlinkWithCompletion:(PFBooleanResultBlock)completion {
    NSParameterAssert(completion != nil);
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

    [self setAuthData:nil forUser:user];
    [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

- (NSDictionary *)twitterAuthData {
    PF_Twitter *twitter = [PFTwitterUtils twitter];
    return @{
        @"auth_token" : twitter.authToken,
        @"auth_token_secret": twitter.authTokenSecret,
        @"consumer_key": kTwitterKey,
        @"consumer_secret": kTwitterSecret,
        @"id": twitter.userId,
        @"screen_name": twitter.screenName,
    };
}

@end
```